# No "Modify Server farm Settings" Dialog when running Configuration Wizard

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard

I installed SharePoint 2013 with SP1 and it didn't ask me for any database access accounts.

After the configuration wizard finished, I tried running it again but it didn't show the dialog where I could modify said settings.

It went straight to the configuration steps. I fear I installed the wrong version of SharePoint or something.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may occur in case, You have select **Standalone Server Type** Instead of **Complete Server Type** during the installation phase.

[image]

So the Specifying configuration Database and database server dialog and Pass Phrase will be skipped.

[image]

---

**The limitation of Standalone Server Type**

- You cannot extend the farm to add a new server, it's only standalone server.
- No domain service, no domain accounts, only local accounts.
- You can't configure User Profile service.
- Because you are using SQL Server Express edition, so each database will be limited to only 10 GB.
- The standalone server type usually used for learning purpose.
- You will not be able to specify the configuration Database and database server.(your situation)
- No need for Pass Phrase because you will not be able to extend your farm.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ended up uninstalling and installing SharePoint again. luckily it's just a dev box and I didn't have any sites configured yet.